# page div/item shudders when hovering certain items

Tags: browser

I have a very unusual behaviour when hovering my menu here:

http://corecruit.w6.ext.starberry.com/employers

It shudders and the links don't work.

You can see this by hovering over the 4 main links or any of the sub-nav links.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing an error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token << jquery.main.js:1.

It looks like the hover state is being applied on mousemove when it should be applied on mouseover or mouseenter. Maybe it's an event bubbling issue that causes the mouseover event to fire constantly.

Upon refreshing the page the problem no longer appears. Did you fix it?

Comment: Apologies... I was trying something, but it didn't work. If you try that same page now (http://corecruit.w6.ext.starberry.com/employers) the top nav will shudder.